# Adding background image to angularJS project

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to set background image for angularJS project. I get the image from backend and here is my code for the mainpage:

```
  <div ui-view="main" ng-class="environmentBackgroundColorClass">
```

I tried adding,

```
  ng-style="{'background-image': 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+backgroundImage}"
```

It doesnt work, whereas the below works.

```
  <img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{backgroundImage}}">
```

Should I use ng-style or ng-src, please help.

backgroundImage has the byte array of image

Comment: Hey , Can you try `<img ng-src="{{'data:image/png;base64,'+backgroundImage}}" >` please? because  `data:image/png;base64`  is a String. you'll need to concat with base64 string

Comment: have you tried `'url(data:image/jpeg;base64,'+backgroundImage+')'` syntax?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Thanks, it works! i did not try this before.. Could you help me in closing this